# How to parse a json using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Below is the json response i am getting from a external service.

```
{"userAttributeList": [  
    {"Name":"PROFILE.UUID","Value":”SL1-4XXXXX0"},  
    {"Name":"PROFILE.UserId","Value":"John.Smith@bigBank.com"},  
    {"Name":"PROFILE.FirstName","Value":"John"},  
    {"Name":"PROFILE.LastName","Value":"Smith"},  
    {"Name":"PROFILE.EmailAddress","Value":"John.Smith@bigBank.com"},  
    {"Name":"SETTING.COMMON.REGIONAL_SETTINGS.DATEFORMAT_DATEPATTERN","Value":"dddd d MMMM yyyy"},  
    {"Name":"SETTING.COMMON.REGIONAL_SETTINGS.DATEFORMAT_TIMEPATTERN","Value":"HH:mm:ss"},  
    {"Name":"SETTING.COMMON.REGIONAL_SETTINGS.DATEFORMAT_TIMEZONE","Value":"Romance Standard Time"}  
]}
```

I am stil trying the figure out a way to deserialize this . Its not in  nor  form. Can any one suggest a way to go a head with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    JSONArray response=new JSONArray(jsonstring);
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject data=response.getJSONObject(i);
        String name=data.getString("Name");
        String values=data.getString("Values");
        //perform operation on name and values
    }
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell in which package of `Gson` library `JSONArray` is placed in?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have an invalid character in here:

```
"Value": ”SL1-4XXXXX0"}
         ^
```

I suggest a) replacing ” with " and b) figuring out why you're getting that in the first place.

Tip: If you're not sure what's wrong with your JSON, check out [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)